# How to export filtered data.frame into desired folder dynamically?

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I've read list of csv files in the folder, now I intend to filter them out given threshold, where dropped rows in each data.frame must be exported to desired folder in dynamic way while saved rows returned as an output. However, I implemented the function to do this task, and it works fine except writing dropped rows as csv files into desired folder is failed. Can anyone point me out what's going in my functions ? Any efficient way to write data.frame in specific folder dynamically ? How can I correct implementation ? Any idea ?

reproducible data:

```
myData <- list(
  df_1 = data.frame( L1=seq(3, by=4, len=16), L2=seq(7, by=4, len=16), score=sample(30, 16)),
  df_2 = data.frame( L1=seq(6, by=7, len=20), L2=seq(14, by=7, len=20), score=sample(30, 20)),
  df_3 = data.frame( L1=seq(11, by=8, len=25), L2=seq(19, by=8, len=25), score=sample(30, 25))
  )
```

I implement this function, it works fine except writing csv files is not desired:

```
func <- function(mlist, threshold=NULL, outDir=getwd(), .fileName=NULL, ...) {
  if(!dir.exists(outDir)) {
    dir.create(file.path(outDir))
    setwd(file.path(outDir))
  }
  rslt <- lapply(mlist, function(x) {
    .drop <- x[x$score < threshold,]
    # FIXME : write droped rows of each data.frame into specific folder
    write.csv(.drop, sprintf("drop.%s.csv", x), row.names = FALSE)
    .save <- x[x$score >= threshold,]
    return(.save)
  })
  return(rslt)
}
```

This is what I intend to write csv file in specific location: concatenate with .initPath `.initPath = getwd()`, create new folder and write csv files there. I don't understand what went wrong in my implementation, I got an error.

How can I write dropped rows from each data.frame into specific folder dynamically ? Is there any quick way to make this happen more efficiently ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the error you receive? And how are you calling the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, in your `write.csv()` line, you are concatenating the dataframe object, `x`, into the file name with `sprintf()`. You need to concatenate the **name** of the dataframe object to the file name.

So, consider replacing your `lapply()` with a `Map()` function (and `Map` being a wrapper to `mapply(func, x, y, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)` where you pass two arguments for `mlist` itself and `mlist` names. Do note: you might think that using `names(x)` in original setup would work but this returns the column names of corresponding dataframe which still will fail in concatenating to a filename string.

```
func <- function(mlist, threshold=NULL, outDir=getwd(), .fileName=NULL, ...) {
  if(!dir.exists(outDir)) {
    dir.create(file.path(outDir))
    setwd(file.path(outDir))
  }
  rslt <- Map(function(x, y) {
    .drop <- x[x$score < threshold,]

    write.csv(.drop, sprintf("drop.%s.csv", y), row.names = FALSE)
    .save <- x[x$score >= threshold,]
    return(.save)
  }, mlist, names(mlist))
  return(rslt)
}

# EXAMPLE
newData <- func(myData, threshold=10)
```

And if you do want to keep `lapply()`, create temp variables to capture `df` object and `df` name. Also below shows how to allow dynamic path and file name changes by passing such values into args and concatenating all with `sprintf()`:

```
func <- function(mlist, threshold=NULL, csvName="", outDir=getwd(), .fileName=NULL, ...) {
  if(!dir.exists(outDir)) {
    dir.create(file.path(outDir))
    setwd(file.path(outDir))
  }
  rslt <- lapply(seq_along(mlist), function(x) {
    df <- mlist[[x]]; dfname <- names(mlist)[x]
    .drop <- df[df$score < threshold,]

    write.csv(.drop, sprintf("%s/%s.%s.csv", outDir, csvName, dfname), row.names = FALSE)
    .save <- df[df$score >= threshold,]
    return(.save)
  })
  return(rslt)
}

# EXAMPLE
newData <- func(myData, threshold=10, csvName=usercsv, outDir=userpath)
```

Comment: If I intend to let user choose the name of exported csv files by custom, also give freedom to choose where they going to save the file, How can I make this happen ? Thank you :)

Comment: See edit where you pass csv name and path name as args to function and concatenate all in `sprintf()` when assigning file name.

Comment: Replace the last `return` line with: `return(setNames(rslt, names(mlist)))` or update `rslt` to this value and return `rslt`.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, appreciated :)